# JavaScript add space to a string after 2 characters but ignore newline character

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

I have to insert a space after every two characters in a string but by completely ignoring the newline character. I am able to do the spacing part but the problem comes with the newline as that is also counted as a character and when rendering the string it adds space at wrong positions.

```js
let str = '23456\n734526754'
console.log(str)

str = str.match(/.{2}/g).join(' ');
console.log(str)
```

For the above code the output comes as

```
23 45 67 
3 45 26 75 3
```

What should be the ideal output is

```
23 45 67 
34 52 67 53
```

How can I ignore the newline character completely?

Comment: What is the expected output? `23 45 67 34....`?

Comment: I've added the snippet back. That is not the output generated by your current code.

Comment: `.` matches any character other than `\n` so your code will produce `23 45 73 45 26 75`.

Comment: The first part has `23456` and the second part has `734526754` In the expected outcome the leading `7` f the second part is at the end of the first part, is that correct? Is there any logic to it?

Comment: edited your required multiple output solution regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update your code.

```js
let str = '234562\n7345267542';
str = str.replace(/(.{2})/g, "$1 ").trim();
console.log(str);
```

**Solution details :**

```
1. expression .{2} matches two characters
2. $1 is for adding space after each group of 2 character
3. g is for match all values
4. trim method removes any leading and trailing whitespace from string
```

Comment: missing the last 6 from first line and last 4 from second

Comment: If the input value is changed to '234562\n7345267542', the result is not as expected. There is a space after 6. The newline character should not be counted as a character, that is where I am facing difficulties. So the desired  output for above is 23 45 62 then a line break and 73 45 26 75 42.

Comment: code edited for get required output

Answer (score 1):

You may use this spacer function in Javascript:

```js
function spacer(s) {
   return s
     .replace(/^((?:.{2})*.)\n(.)(.*)/g, '$1$2\n$3')
     .replace(/.{2}(?=.)/g, '$& ');
}

console.log(spacer('23456\n734526754'));
//=> '23 45 67\n34 52 67 54'

console.log(spacer('234562\n7345267542'));
//=> '23 45 62\n73 45 26 75 42'
```

**Solution Details:**

- `spacer` function user 2 `.replace` invocations
- First `.replace` finds `\n` after matching odd number of characters   and moves it one position ahead using 3 capture groups
- Second `.replace` matches a pair of any characters (except line break) and inserts a space after the match

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using a single regex replacement:

```js
var str = '23456\n734526754';
var output = str.replace(/(\S{1,2})(?=\S)/g, "$1 ");
console.log(output);
```

The regex pattern used here says to match:

- `(\S{1,2})` match AND capture either 1 or 2 non whitespace characters
- `(?=\S)` assert that non whitespace follows (do not add space after final group)

Then, we replace with `$1`  to effectively add a space after each group.